# Rule engines for java application

Tags: java, rule-engine

i want to use some rule engines for my application which is in java. so can you suggest some good rule frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [JESS](http://www.jessrules.com/)
- [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/)
- ["Top 10 Java Business Rule Engines"](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/top-10-java-business-rule-engines/)

Answer (score 3):

[DROOLS](http://www.jboss.org/drools/) is the first one that pops into my mind...

There are probably more of those out there, but I would not know as I have next to no experience with 3rd party rule engines...

OTOH: Depending on the complexity of your task, you can also roll your own by including any number of scripting languages and providing their execution environments

[Clojure](http://clojure.org/) is probably a good match if you need to be able to define your rules in a semi-declarative syntax (that it has from it's Lisp heritage)

[Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) has a more natural syntax for an average Java programmer, so it is also a good choice...

And finally, if you know your domain well enough, or if the task is not too complex, you can easily roll your own.

I would suggest trying [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) to define your rule syntax and generate [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/) models of the rules domain and make an engine yourself. XText can even generate you a full blown Eclipse text editor plug-in for your syntax with syntax highlighting, outline, intellisense auto-complete and all the other goodies you'd expect from an IDE text editor...

Answer (score 0):

[WebSphere ILOG JRules BRMS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/products/business-rule-management/) (by IBM)

Comment: i have been trying out ILOG JRules from Rule studio IDE ( eclipse ) . using the trial version 7.1.xx , the intellisense is bit buggy.I tried to vocabularize rules and it was not popping up in the intelli menu ,  maybe the full version will have the fixes , other than that , ILOG Jrules is a good option,good documentation from IBM , but u wudnt get help from any other resources on the web.